# How to concatenate 2 set of data in datetime class into one by python

Tags: python, datetime, concatenation

If I have 2 sets of data in datetime class name date_rage_before and date_rage_afterwhich contain the data like these

date_rage_before -->

2019-08-26 00:00:00
2019-08-27 00:00:00
2019-08-28 00:00:00
2019-08-29 00:00:00
2019-08-30 00:00:00
2019-08-31 00:00:00
2019-09-01 00:00:00
2019-09-02 00:00:00
2019-09-03 00:00:00
2019-09-04 00:00:00
2019-09-05 00:00:00
2019-09-06 00:00:00
2019-09-07 00:00:00
2019-09-08 00:00:00

and date_rage_after -->
2019-09-08 00:00:00
2019-09-09 00:00:00
2019-09-10 00:00:00
2019-09-11 00:00:00
2019-09-12 00:00:00
2019-09-13 00:00:00
2019-09-14 00:00:00
2019-09-15 00:00:00
2019-09-16 00:00:00
2019-09-17 00:00:00
2019-09-18 00:00:00
2019-09-19 00:00:00
2019-09-20 00:00:00
2019-09-21 00:00:00

Both of them is class 'datetime.datetime'

So, I want to merge them into one datetime data set by eliminate the same value. How can I do it ?

Comment: You can just insert all of it to set. Set removes duplicates

Comment: You could also use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) inside of a set-comprehension to loop over both of the variables at the same time: `{i for i in itertools.chain(x, y)}`